# jquery select input options, except one

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a multi-select that holds many sources for whence a visitor came.  I am also including an option (with the value of "all") in the top of all the options.

When someone clicks that option, then all the options will be selected.  And that part is easy. I've included the multi-select and jquery that listens for a click event.

```
<select name="sourceid[]" id="sourceid" style="width:230px;" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="all">-- Select All Sources --</option>
  <option value="1">Internet</option>
  <option value="2">Radio</option>
  <option value="3">Phone</option>
  <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>


$("#sourceid").click(function(){

  if($(this).val()=='all'){ $("#sourceid option").attr("selected","selected"); }

});
```

So far it works great!
The jquery will also select the top option, naturally.

Is there a way to tell jquery to exclude selecting that one option?

Comment: You better use `change` instead of `click`. This ill also capture selects with the keyboard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this selector

```
$("option[value!=all]")
```

All options where the attribute value is not `all`, [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7tZ8/)

[Attribute not equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) jQuery API

Answer (score 3):

Try this using jQuery's [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector

```
$("#sourceid").click(function(){

  if($(this).val()=='all'){ 
            $("#sourceid option").not(this)
                   .attr("selected","selected"); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$("#sourceid option").not(':first').attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I would use a checkbox list instead and then have a select all that checks all the boxes instead of using a dropdown...

Comment: Yes, that's an option.  This is simply a preference I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the problem; just add `disabled` to the top option. You don't want them to be able to submit that option, anyway.

```
<select name="sourceid[]" id="sourceid" style="width:230px;" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="all" disabled>-- Select All Sources --</option>
  <option value="1">Internet</option>
  <option value="2">Radio</option>
  <option value="3">Phone</option>
  <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: True!  it does stop jquery from recognizing the click event, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not slector like this:

```
 $("#sourceid :not(option[value='all'])").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sourceid option[value=all]").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().attr("selected","selected");
});
```

maybe its better:

```
$("#sourceid option[value=all]").click(function(){
if($(this).siblings("[selected=selected]").size() == $(this).siblings().size()) {
    $(this).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
} else {
    $(this).siblings().attr("selected","selected");
}
});
```